# Bash built-in that always fails with specific error code?

Tags: bash, shell

I think I can write this myself as

```
unrollme-dev-dan:~ Dan$ echo 'exit $@' > fail
unrollme-dev-dan:~ Dan$ chmod +x fail
unrollme-dev-dan:~ Dan$ ./fail 42
unrollme-dev-dan:~ Dan$ echo $?
42
```

Is there a built-in that does this?  `exit` of course will not work because it will exit your current process, not create a child process and exit from that. `test` is the easiest way I found to simply get `0` or `1` as a return code.

Similar to http://httpstat.us/ I need to unit test specific error codes. This has been surprisingly hard to Google for since most results are to handle errors, not cause them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily create a child process and exit from it with a return code:

```
( exit 42 )
```

Comment: well I've always wondered what the parentheses do, besides mess up my greps I forget to quote.

Comment: Parentheses create a subshell, which is literally a subprocess (except for some weird exception in `ksh`). That it's a new process protects you from impacting the parent process in various ways, but for this use case it's just mildly more expensive than a function.

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be any such built in in POSIX. If there's a nonstandard utility, I don't know about it, but you can just compose a trivial shell function, such as

```
fail() {
  return $(( $1 ))
}
```

The arithmetic expression guards against non-numeric values. You could write

```
a=6
fail a
```

and you'd get an exit status of 6. If you just wrote `return $1` you'd get an error from the shell.